# Export data from FamilySearch.org Family Tree as spreadsheet?

Tags: familysearch.org, data-transfer

I want to generate a spreadsheet of everyone I have in my FamilySearch.org family tree.  I want the data associated with these names as well (birth, marriage, death related info).  Is there a tool to do this or do I have to go through manually? I am open to all options for this.

Comment: What would your desired spreadsheet look like?  Perhaps you can use a test tree of a few individuals to illustrate your requirement?

Comment: Just a table with columns for name, DOB,POB, Date of Marriage, Place of Marriage, Date of Death, Place of Death.  I want to map out all of the significant events in my ancestors' lives, but I don't want to use one of the programs that will do it for you because I want to do more with it.

Comment: If you are planning to map it then putting out lat/long would seem to be important.  Rather than go to Excel perhaps you could look for GEDCOM to Geodatabase, Shapefile or KML convertors.

Comment: If I can get the city/state/country of these events in a spreadsheet I can geocode them to derive lat/lon.

Comment: What do you mean by your tree? You don't own anything on FamilySearch, so there is no such thing as your tree.

Comment: By tree I mean my family tree that I have created and added information to on FamilySearch.org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the help / FAQ on the FamilySearch site it states that there is currently no way to export your tree from FamilySearch. It goes on to say that this may be possible with a third party application.

So unfortunately it looks as though you may have to do this manually.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it.  I was just hoping someone knew what 3rd party app would do this if any.

Comment: Doing some searching on Google has come up with these two links but it isn't easy. http://support.legacyfamilytree.com/article/AA-00387/0/How-to-download-your-ancestors-from-FamilySearch-Family-Tree-into-Legacy.html and https://getsatisfaction.com/familysearch/topics/exporting_ged_or_paf_friendly_files_from_family_search_family_tree_for_import_into_a_stand_alone_program_such_as (read the threads at the bottom of this post).

Comment: Apparently the [API is closed to the public](https://www.familysearch.org/innovate/app-approval-considerations) now, so it's not easy/possible to build a tool to use their API to get a spreadsheet from your data :/

Answer (score 5):

You *can* use the Family Search API even though they have no already written tools. This is suggested in the [link](http://support.legacyfamilytree.com/article/AA-00387/0/How-to-download-your-ancestors-from-FamilySearch-Family-Tree-into-Legacy.html) Colin left in [his answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/10573/6103).

Specifically, someone has written [a python script](https://github.com/Linekio/getmyancestors) that exports to GEDCOM. Not sure how well that translates to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Tools do exist that convert GEDCOM to spreadsheets and vice-versa.  I'll leave that for you to explore, in case you want to improve the quality of your answer. ;-)  Welcome, and have fun exploring the site!

Comment: Maybe you could just answer the question with what you know about this.

Comment: There is an interesting list here: http://www.cyndislist.com/gedcom/gedcom-software/?page=2. I am looking forward to trying the python script exporting to GEDCOM first before recommending anything. This one appears to be free and looks interesting: http://www.gedmagic.com/GEDxlate.htm

Comment: This one is also free and open source - written in C# it appears - and outputs to xml, which excel can import. http://www.gedmagic.com/GEDxlate.htm. But if we're importing from the API, why export to GEDCOM first, and then to xml, and then to excel? It could be easier to import the FamilySearch JSON objects directly into Excel with an addin like this one: http://excel-requests.pathio.com/en/master/. It all depends on your comfort level with technology.

Comment: Do you all know if these scripts / techniques of using the API is still possible? I see on their docs that [the API has been disabled for public use](https://www.familysearch.org/innovate/app-approval-considerations)? Would love to get a spreadsheet from the family tree my family painstakingly put together on this site.

Comment: @Lance sorry, I haven't made an attempt since a bit after the time I posted this answer.